# VIP Wordpress REST API - Auotcreate Post and Page

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I want to write a program which will create bulk post and bulk pages through a rest api in VIP Wordpress.

According to [VIP Wordpress Developer Documentation](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/api/), it states that wordpress rest api are supported.

and [Wordpress Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/) allows us to create both post and pages via rest api.

I do not have access to a VIP wordpress, but has anyone tried to autocreate posts or pages in wordpress using REST API?

Are there any issues regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create post page by Rest API in wordpress you have to get authorization which is basically cookies auth , basic auth and oauth.

in bellow i have done by basic auth

```
 <?php 
$headers = array (
//  'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'username:password' ),
// );

// $response = wp_remote_request( 'url', array(
//  'method' => 'method',
//  'headers' => $headers
// ));
?>
```

i hope it will be little help for you mate